# SMD capacitor identification

Tags: capacitor, motor, 12v

I have a exploded aluminum electrolytic SMD capacitor on a 12v somfy wireless blind motor controller (r28) with the markings

```
125
220
6Z
```

I'm trying to figure out what the markings mean so I can replace it. Is it 22v 125uf? Or 220v 125uf? Or 125v 22uf or 125v 220uf? Or something else? Which configuration would make the most sense with this?

[image]

Comment: or a 125uF 6V or a 220uF 6V... This is why I hate surface mount...

Comment: Every e-CAP can be different.  But this one has no trademark.  Usually has Lot#, capacitance and voltage code

Comment: Yup I'd guess 220uF 6V, 125V or 220V would be way too much for something like this.

Comment: or uF  Voltage, Series and date code

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 yup, but would u expect a 125V or 220V one to be on that.. and be that small... 125uF is an odd number too. But who knows

Comment: I don't know too much about capacitors, but if I know if I replace this with something of higher voltage it's fine. However for this application is it also fine if I replace them with capacitors with higher capacitance?

Comment: Impossible to tell. Some variance in capacitance may be ok, but without knowing what they are actually doing nobody can tell you for sure. I think I'd change both of them though if I was going to do that.

Comment: Remember though, a larger cap will be physically bigger too. Make sure it fits the footprint and inside whatever this thing is enclosed in.

Comment: I ended up getting a 6.3v 220uf cap. I believe this is the right one. Maybe the 125 is the lot code. Maybe this is the [datasheet](http://studylib.net/doc/18041713/su-surface-mount-aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors) (no manufacturer however)